# "Тверд как камень", "oн тверд как камень" - нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Тверд как камень. Он тверд как камень.**

Нужны ли запятые в приведенных предложениях? Влияет ли местоимение на присутствие/отсутствие запятой во втором предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя существует **список распространенных фразеологизмов**, в которых сравнительный оборот имеет значение одного слова и не обособляется, но это не абсолютное решение, и обособление может зависеть от вида конкретного предложения.

1) **Он как камень**. Отсутствие тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при наличии союза.

2) Выражение **тверд как камень**:  сравнительный оборот может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от структуры предложения.

**Тверд как кАмень. Он тверд как кАмень.**  Запятая не ставится в нераспространенном предложении, нет паузы, ударение падает на сравнительный оборот.

Однако в распространенном предложении может быть другая расстановка ударений, тогда оборот может обособляться.

**Примеры:**

1) Авторское решение (два варианта):

Пока он строится, грунт под ним **тверд как кАмень**. [В. А. Мезенцев. Чудеса: Популярная энциклопедия. Том 1 (1991)]

Грунт наверное страшно затравянел **и твЁрд, как кАмень.** [Б. Л. Пастернак. Доктор Живаго (1945-1955)]

2) Оборот обособляется:

― Хорошо тому, кто привык к холоду и жару,  кто легко переносит голод и жажду, **кто твЁрд, как кАмень, и подвИжен, как вЕтер**...[Н. П. Вагнер. Сказки Кота-Мурлыки (1872)]

Comment: @ Jasminи все же оборот лучше не обособлять. Обратите внимание на год публикаций этих примеров.

Comment: Я обратила внимание, просто других примеров под рукой не было. Но Вагнера и сейчас печатают в том же виде. Здесь еще важно то, что конструкции с союзом КАК должны произноситься одинаково. Да и Пастернака вряд ли меняют.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна. Это устойчивое выражение, фразеологизм. Они пишутся без запятых.

Comment: Влияет ли местоимение на присутствие/отсутствие запятой во втором предложении?

Comment: Конечно, нет. С чего вдруг местоимению влиять на запятую во фразеологизме?